# Write short way test Cypress test

Tags: cypress

I am trying to write short test cypress for this test, how the best way to write it ?

```
describe('test', () => {
    it('test 1', () => {
        cy.get('[data-cy=edit]').first().click()
        cy.get('[data-cy=t-input]').clear().type('123123123123123')
        cy.get('[data-cy=s-button]').click()
        cy.get('[data-cy=popup]').should('be.visible')
      })
    
      it('test2', () => {
        cy.get('[data-cy=edit]').first().click()
        cy.get('[data-cy=t-input]').clear().type('1231231231231216')
        cy.get('[data-cy=s-button]').click()
        cy.get('[data-cy=c-div]').find('div')
          .should('have.class', 'error')
          .and('exist')
      })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom commands and write the repeated lines there. From your test I could see these three lines being repeated, you can add these under custom command:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=edit]').first().click()
cy.get('[data-cy=t-input]').clear().type('123123123123123')
cy.get('[data-cy=s-button]').click()
```

Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('addCardDetails', (cardNumber) => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=edit]').first().click()
    cy.get('[data-cy=t-input]').clear().type(cardNumber)
    cy.get('[data-cy=s-button]').click()
})
```

And in your tests you can just write:

```
cy.addCardDetails('123123123123123')
```

So Now your tests will look like:

```
describe('test', () => {
    it('test 1', () => {
        cy.addCardDetails('123123123123123')
        cy.get('[data-cy=popup]').should('be.visible')
    })
  
    it('test2', () => {
        cy.addCardDetails('1231231231231216')
        cy.get('[data-cy=c-div]').find('div').should('have.class', 'error').and('exist')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this logic inside a single JS file, it's easier to create a simple JavaScript function to extract the common logic.

So your tests will look like:

```js
    describe('test', () => {

        function addCardDetails(cardNumber) {
            cy.get('[data-cy=edit]').first().click()
            cy.get('[data-cy=t-input]').clear().type(cardNumber)
            cy.get('[data-cy=s-button]').click()
        })
    
        it('test 1', () => {
            addCardDetails('123123123123123')
            cy.get('[data-cy=popup]').should('be.visible')
        })
      
        it('test2', () => {
            addCardDetails('1231231231231216')
            cy.get('[data-cy=c-div]').find('div').should('have.class', 'error').and('exist')
        })
    })
```

Cypress docs [recommends](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#1-Don-t-make-everything-a-custom-command) using a function instead of a custom command whenever possible.